# Any ideas how to determine what age group an individual belongs in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, case

I have 2 columns in an Excel spread sheet.

First column header is called AGE and the second column header is called Age_Group.

The ages in the AGE column are between 18 and 45.

There could be multiple rows with same age.

I am tasked with determining what age group a certain age falls into and then print out that age group.

For instance, if someone’s age is 18, I would like to use IF statement or CASE statement to determine that age 18 is between 18 and 24 and then put that value into Age_Group column as 18-24.

If age is 19, again, it will fall into the group of 18-24 in Age_Group column.

If the age in the Age column falls between 25 and 29, then they will be in Age_Group column as 25-29.
Here is an example:

```
AGE                            AGE_GROUP
18                               18-24
19                               18-24, 
25                               25-29
28                               25-29
```

If you would be kind to share some code, I can use it to calculate the rest till we reach 45.

I am not good with Excel VBA. Any assistance with IF or CASE statement would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want VBA or Excel formula based solution? :)

Comment: Hi @bonCodigo, thanks for your response. Either solution would be fine. If formula is simpler, then great. Otherwise, vba is fine.

Comment: Please take a look at the `VBA` solution then :) What you need to do is, just enter the `Age` as function parameter, it will return the `Age Group`. Very basic function, so not much error handling is done. Let me know if it works for you first. Try this on a cell `=whatagegroup(E7)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a VBA code: But surely you are better off with that Excel VLOOKUP. :)

1. First [add module to a VBA project](http://fontstuff.com/vba/vbatut03.htm).
2. Copy the following

code.

```
Option Explicit


Function whatAgeGroup(ByVal i As Integer) As String
    Select Case i
        Case IsEmpty(i)
            whatAgeGroup = "No Age Entered"
        Case 18 To 24:
            whatAgeGroup = "18-24"
        Case 25 To 29
            whatAgeGroup = "25-29"
        Case 30 To 34
            whatAgeGroup = "30-34"
        Case 35 To 39
            whatAgeGroup = "35-39"
        Case 40 To 44
            whatAgeGroup = "40-44"
        Case Is >= 45
            whatAgeGroup = "45 and Above"
        Case Else
           whatAgeGroup = "WhatGroup?"
        End Select
End Function
```

1. enter the function name in a cell and enter, as per the image shown.

Comment: But @bonCodigo, unless I misunderstand Dave, I would need to create a database table?

If someone would be kind enough to explain how VLookup works, I would be glad to use it.

Comment: What do you ened to create a database table? He is just telling that you need to [`name the range`](http://www.contextures.com/xlNames01.html) and used that `named range` as your data range to lookup :) In `VBA case` you have a column with all the ages and all you need to do is just enter that cell into the function and enter :) Then it will give you the relevant `Age_Group` as per what you set in the `case` statement.

Comment: thanks for your help and patience. I tried the function but it isn't doing anything. Just to make sure I am using it correctly, I call it like the following: whatAgeGroup(age)? and I put that code on the first row under the Age_Group column. am I using it correctly?

I also tried the vlookup. First I name the excel workbook as Age_Group_Table. Then I use VLOOKUP(A1, AGE_GROUP_TABLE, 2, TRUE) on first column under Age_group colum. It is not doing anything either. I am sure it is a user error.

Comment: Let's go step by step, did you name the range as per the link in my comment? :) The range means the cells with Ages..

Comment: I take back the statement that your function isn't doing anything. It is actually calculating, except that every row has same value of 18-24 age group. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Alright please try out the updated function. There wasn't much difference anyway. I have also added how output should look like :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @bonCodigo. The function worked. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Then upvote :P Glad you got it worked. I am trying to upload that image of the sheet. However there's an issue in my side. But please give a try for `VLOOKUP` as well :)

Answer (score 7):

Use a vlookup. Create a two column table with the lower bound of your age range in the first column and  the age range as text in the second column like so:

```
AGE_LOOKUP  AGE_GROUP
18          18-24
25          25-29
30          30-35
36          36-37 etc..
```

Name this table's range as AGE_GROUP_TABLE then using the following formula to get the age group:

```
VLOOKUP(A1, AGE_GROUP_TABLE, 2, TRUE)
```

Put different ages into cell A1 and the formula will return the correct age group. The important thing to remember is to make sure that the last parameter of the VLOOKUP is set to TRUE, this makes the VLOOKUP find the nearest match.

Comment: the file was sent to us in Excel sheet. We wouldn't want to create a table and besides they are random. You could see 18 in first row and then another in say, 15th row.

Comment: @ChidiOkeh -> you don't need to create a `Table` like in Access. You just need to create a table in Excel, table meaning a data structure with two columns (with headers) and rows of data. If you place the numbers 18 - 37 (or however high) down the rows and place the age groups next to them, as Dave has done, you can then use `vlookup` against the table to find the group. Use Excel help or google to find out about vlookup.

Answer (score 1):

As the idea of a Table was causing some confusion I thought I would also share my favourite trick of a self contained, table free, VLOOKUP using an embedded array. So for the current problem it would look something like this:

```
VLOOKUP(A1, {18,"18-24";25,"25-29";30,"30-35";36,"36-37"}, 2 TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

While the vlookup solution is excellent, you can also do that with a PivotTable. Make sure the age is the row heading, then right click the Age "square" and select Group. This is avery easy and dynamic.